# Asp.Net set different css classes for generating items in Datalist

Tags: css, asp.net, set, datalist

I have one DataList control like this:

```
    <asp:DataList ID="DataList1" runat="server" DataKeyField="ID"
     DataSourceID="DS_GET_CATEGORY" RepeatDirection="Horizontal">
       <ItemTemplate>
           <div ><%#Eval("NAME") %>
           </div>
       </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:DataList>
```

I want to set the different css classes for `<div>` elements after generate Datalist control. Can someone help me, please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can follow below steps.

1. first create **DB view** which contain one extra column as **CssClass**

`<asp:DataList ID="DataList1" runat="server" DataKeyField="ID"
     DataSourceID="DS_GET_CATEGORY" RepeatDirection="Horizontal">
       <ItemTemplate>
           <div class='<%#Eval("CssClass") %>'>
              <%#Eval("NAME") %>
           </div>
       </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:DataList>`